# Can I use "to talked" in this situtation?

Tags: infinitives

> My mother called me every night **to talked** with me and **encouraged** me.

Can I use *to talked* in this sentence?

Comment: Infinitives use the base form of the word: *to talk*.

Comment: My mother calls me every night to talk with me and to encourage me.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen here if OP meant to say his mother calls him on regular bases then your your answer is correct. But as he tried to you past tense, I can feel this process of calling is Past now.

Comment: How can use this in past simple?

Comment: The answer may surprise you, Thien Nguyen: "My mother called me every night to talk with me and to encourage me." The only past tense you need is in the verb "called"; the infinitives "to talk" and "to encourage" remain unchanged whether the remainder of the sentence is cast as past ("called"), present ("calls"), or future ("will call").

Answer (score 2):

After 'to' in sentence like this, there is always base verb regardless of any tense.

So even when your mother called you every night and this process is past now, still when you use 'to' to show her motive to call you (here to talk with you)
there should not past tense of verb talk.

Correct sentence will be "My mother called me every night to talk with me and to encourage me."

there are some articles on internet on this topic, attaching links of some

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-rules-of-using-the-word-to-before-a-verb

https://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/viewpoints/mind-our-english/2011/10/20/to-before-a-verb/